# Javascript Json object, get by value by Key String.. Ex : GetMyVal(MyKeyInString)

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json info:

```
data.ContactName
data.ContactEmal
data.Departement
```

I Would like to have a function like that

```
function GetMyVal(myStringKey)
{
   $.Ajax
         ,... 
         , ...
         ,success :function(data)
    {
       $("#mytarget").val(data.myStringKey);
    }

}
```

Call Like that `GetMyVal("ContactName");`

Comment: You guys , give me 3 good answer.... I just don't know where I put the green check mark to specify as an Answer. To be fair, I'll roll the dice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution:

Try changing:

```
$("#mytarget").val(data.myStringKey);
```

to:

```
$("#mytarget").val(data[myStringKey]);
```

### Explanation:

Here is what those constructs mean:

**`$("#mytarget").val(SOMETHING);`**
change the value of the element with id "mytarget" to SOMETHING

**`data.myStringKey`**
take the object named "data" and give me the value of its property named **literally** "myStringKey"

**`data[myStringKey]`**
take the object named "data" and give me the value of its property named like a **value** of the variable named "myStringKey"

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
   $('#mytarget').val(data[myStringKey]);
```

In JavaScript, the construct:

```
   reference_to_object [ expression ]
```

means to evaluate the expression, and then use its string value as a property name to look up a property in the referenced object.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
$("#mytarget").val(data[myStringKey]);
```